# I want to draw lines as the jsp will get new lat and long every second

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to draw lines as the jsp will get new lat and long every second.

At http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/209616/A-simple-GPS-based-application-to-record-current-l - there is an image showing lines of markers in a map.

if the new values of x and y will be same as the previous then it will stop until it gets different value. Please help me.

unlike this image there wouldn't be the markers. instead of those markers lines are to be made between every two points.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more what are you trying to achieve - JSP is not a 2D drawing framework. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp

Comment: If you are using google maps API then you should use the corresponding SDK https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays This question has absolutely nothing to do with jsp or servlets because it's about client side programming.

Answer (score 0):

To draw a line you can use http://jsdraw2d.jsfiction.com/

for checking value change you can easily compare that or use listener classes.

Comment: i mean using google map in JSP. and sorry i am using stackoverflow first time. so please bear with me.